# Possibly hacked delicious account suddenly containing links to adult sites etc - is there an alternative for delicious

Tags: bookmarks, delicious

I was searching for some academic publications I saved earlier on delicious. To my astonishment, there are a lot of tags and links in my account, that point to adult material from a Brazillian site (Portugeuse or Spanish), and lots of links to European sports site (in German or Dutch).

Most of these links are public, and it seems my account has been hacked. I searched the delicious site to see if I could report the issue, and ofcourse there is no contact details.

I've had just about enough with delicious (first, they changed their login system after being taken over - resulting in me losing over a year's worth of bookmarks), now this.

Is there a replacement online bookmarking service someone can recommend?

Comment: In Brazil they speak Portugese. Also, read the site's FAQ: "[This site] is not about ... websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress".

Comment: Just do the obvious thing.  Secure the account by changing the password to something you have not used before.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli - This isn't the stackexchange website to ask for advice on websites like delicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://alternativeto.net/software/delicious/ lists some possible replacements.

no.1:

> "[Diigo](http://www.diigo.com/)" (DEE-go) is a Social bookmarking website which allows signed-up users to bookmark and tag web-pages. Additionally, it allows users to highlight any part of a webpage and attach sticky notes to specific highli ...

no.2:

> [Google Bookmarks](https://www.google.com/bookmarks/) is a free online bookmark storage service, available to Google Account holders. It allows one to bookmark favorite websites and add labels or tags, and also notes.Users can access their bookmarks from a ...

Comment: Google bookmarks it is then ... Thanks for actually answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Faviki](http://www.faviki.com/).

One advantage over Delicious:

Tags are semantic, so everybody collaborates on the same tags. No synonyms. No ambiguities.

Tags are actually in part the database of the English Wikipedia's articles names. Auto-completion helps you find the thing you mean. For instance Java (island), not Java (programming language).

As a result, search becomes much more meaningful.

Comment: Faviki seems nice, but its the old catch 22 unfortunately. I don't really want to spend tuime importing my bookmarks to a beta service, only for it to go "pear shaped" further down the line. I think Google is the safer option here.

Comment: I was already using Faviki 5 years ago.